# ExpressionEngine piracy?

Tags: php

I used to run a fairly basic Joomla website for a real estate company. Over the years it got way too large for Joomla so they decided to hire a developer to get their own CMS, where the database could be updated offline and the website synched with it. (I'm just a basic self-taught amateur web designer so this is over my head)
Long story short: they put that CMS, which used elements of ExpressionEngine, on my server but as it grew larger than 10GB I had to upgrade my own hosting package in order for it to keep up. The problem was that as soon as it was moved the database stopped working. The backend seemed fine and the owner of the business could still see all the properties, but on the homepage there was a message saying the licence was not valid for this domain. ("The local license key is invalid for this location. Manage your license.")
My suspicion is that this site was developed in not so legit ways as the developer threw a fit that I had moved the site, saying it is a nightmare to configure, etc. My hosting company never believed this and I am also inclined to mistrust said developer, who I think is hiding behind "it's complicated". The site was offline for 5 days and he's moved it to his own host now, so has full control.
My knowledge is too limited to be 100% sure about this. This is basically a PHP driven CMS with Ioncube on it. The developer said Ioncube is what was making it hard to migrate to a different server (within same host), but he never answered my question as to why it had Ioncube on it in the first place, and why it was still working fine in the backend.
Can anyone shed light on this? Would you agree this developer is probably a bit shady or am I being paranoid?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about EE and not clear what do you want to hear from community

Comment: Hey FlyingPig - closing this because EE doesn't do license management in this manner, so this is not en EE issue. I'd figure out there license error is coming from first, then look for appropriate help.

Comment: If you open the ExpressionEngine config.php file, you will find a license number (or an empty field if unlicensed). Feel free to email that to team@ellislab.com and we can help you determine if the EE-run portion of this site is legitimate.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this is EE message - EllisLab just don't control they lic this way (at least no yet).

Possible developer made some custom solution (add-on) which he don't want to share with anybody w/o his own profit. And it is his piracy protection.

Comment: I see. I didn't realise EE doesn't do this. So it seems it is the developer who did it, which is fair enough then I guess. Sorry if this is off topic, and thanks for pointing this out.